# using crond to let the yum auto update, is that safe enough?

Tags: centos, centos6, yum

Nowadays, there are many bugs are found. So that, I am wondering, If I use crond to execute yum update -y per day, will it make things better?(It's a server, I don't want it stop working due to this....) Centos 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't safe.

- First off, you have to test whether any update/change in configuration disrupts your production rig's service **in a separate machine**.
- Second, you have to assess yourself the urgency of an update. Some security flaws require doing a sequence of steps including taking the server off the network. No way of putting it in cron.
- Third, there are updates to the kernel necessitating re-booting the machine. Some updates can be postponed till scheduled maintenance, some cannot. Again, in general you cannot let an unpatched kernel run for months between reboots.

**EDIT**: Just in case you are wondering: "*Well, this is a low-value server - does it matter if I automate maintenance and rely on RedHat for the update not to break my stuff?*" - securing your web server **is important** so as not to convert it into a botnet slave rig which would rob your traffic quotas and be a source of unpleasantness for dozens and hundreds hosts worldwide.

Comment: Hello Deer, do you have another recommendation? I want to make my server safer, but no time to manage it often... Thanks

Comment: @HellowHi Those are conflicting requirements - you can hire a person to do sysadmin'ing instead.

Comment: however, that's not server that used for profit, and I would like to manage it myself~ I can't test the programs one by one...